# Python requests session does not rotate proxies

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, ip, proxies

I am using private rotating proxy provided by (https://proxy.webshare.io/proxy/rotating?) in which each request to rotating proxy receives a new IP address. when I am using
`requests.get('https://httpbin.org/get', headers=headers, proxies=get_proxy())`
it returns a new IP each time whenever I make request. but when using

```
session = requests.Session()
session.headers = headers
session.proxies = get_proxy()

session.get('https://httpbin.org/get')
```

It returns same IP each time whenever I make request.
How does session object behaves different from requests.get() function in case of proxies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Session` uses previously set up variables/values for each subsequent request, like Cookies. If you want to change the proxy for each request in the session, then use [Prepared Requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#prepared-requests) to set it each time or just put it in a function:

```
def send(session, url):
    return session.get(url, proxy=get_proxy())

sess = requests.Session()
sess.headers = headers
resp = send(sess, 'https://httpbin.org/get')
print(resp.status_code)
```

But if you're trying to hide your origin IP for scraping or something, you probably *don't want* to persist cookies, etc. so you shouldn't use sessions.

Comment: great, btw why we shouldn't persist cookies, does websites  don't require cookies. also when I try to make request without session, it doesn't work ,for every request it gives captcha. i am using same headers for session and without session.

Comment: There's no point in rotating proxies if you want to maintain cookies / sessions. The website can still identify you as you. So just use a regular session without changing proxies. (Use just one or none at all.)

Answer (score 0):

The following code works, and it take a proxylistfile.txt file to check every proxy:

```
from requests import *
import bs4 
import sys 

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print('Usage: ./testproxy.py <proxylistfile.txt>')
    sys.exit()

ifco = 'http://ifconfig.co'
PROXIES_FILE = sys.argv[1]
proxy = dict()

with open(PROXIES_FILE) as file:
    for line in file:
        if line[0] == '#' or line == "\n":
            continue
        line_parts = line.replace('\n', '').split(':')
        proxy['http'] = f'{line_parts[0]}://{line_parts[1]}:{line_parts[2]}'
        try:
            i = get(ifco, proxies=proxy, timeout=11)
            print(f"{proxy['http']} - successfull - IP ---> ", end='')
            zu = bs4.BeautifulSoup(i.text, 'html.parser')
            testo = zu.findAll('p', text=True)[0].get_text()
            print(testo)
        except:
            print(f"{proxy['http']} - unsuccessfull")
            pass
```

It connect ot ifconfig.co site and return its real ip to check if the proxy works.
The output will be something like:

```
http://proxy:port - successfull - IP ---> your.real.ip
```

the input file format should be like:

```
http:1.1.1.1:3128
```

Answer (score -3):

I finally switch to another rotating proxy provider (https://www.proxyegg.com) and the issue has been resolved now.