# Failed to parse content from a webpage using requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, cookies, python-requests

I'm trying to create a script using requests module (`without using session`) to parse two fields from a [webpage](https://compranet.hacienda.gob.mx/web/login.html) but the script fails miserably. However, when I created [another script](https://pastebin.com/n7Bwf8hG) using session, I could fetch the content from that site flawlessly.

Here goes the manual steps to reach the content:

1. Choose the [first item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVf3U.jpg) from dropdown.
2. Get [the links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owpLG.jpg) to the detail page.
3. Grab these [two fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQmXG.jpg) from detail page.

While creating the script using plain requests, I tried to make use of cookies but I ended up getting `AttributeError`.

Script without session:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin

base = 'https://compranet.hacienda.gob.mx'
link = 'https://compranet.hacienda.gob.mx/web/login.html'
vigen_detail_page = 'https://compranet.hacienda.gob.mx/esop/toolkit/opportunity/current/{}/detail.si'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
}

def grab_first_link_from_dropdown(link):
    r = requests.get(link,headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html.parser")
    category_link = urljoin(base,soup.select_one('ul.dropdown-menu > li > a:contains("Vigentes")').get("href"))
    return category_link

def fetch_detail_page_link(cat_link):
    res = requests.get(cat_link,headers=headers)
    str_cookie = f"JSESSIONID={res.cookies['JSESSIONID']}"
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html.parser")
    for items in soup.select("table.list-table > tbody.list-tbody > tr"):
        target_link = items.select_one("a.detailLink").get("onclick")
        detail_num = re.findall(r"goToDetail\(\'(\d+?)\'",target_link)[0]
        inner_link = vigen_detail_page.format(detail_num)
        yield str_cookie,inner_link

def get_content(str_cookie,inner_link):
    headers['Cookie'] = str_cookie
    res = requests.get(inner_link,headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html.parser")
    try:
        expediente = soup.select_one(".form_question:contains('Código del Expediente') + .form_answer").get_text(strip=True)
    except AttributeError: expediente = ""
    try:
        descripcion = soup.select_one(".form_question:contains('Descripción del Expediente') + .form_answer").get_text(strip=True)
    except AttributeError: descripcion = ""
    return expediente,descripcion

if __name__ == '__main__':
    category_link = grab_first_link_from_dropdown(link)
    for cookie,detail_page_link in fetch_detail_page_link(category_link):
        print(get_content(cookie,detail_page_link))
```

> ***What possible change should I bring about to make the script work?***

Comment: You already have a working solution and what's wrong with using `session`?

Comment: I don't think my question is unclear enough to understand what I'm trying to achieve? I've also tried myself before posing this question. Btw, answering a question by posing a counter question is not a good idea @baduker, right?

Comment: You have a working solution. Then you take the part out that makes the soultion work just to ask  *what possible change should I bring about to make the script work*. What's the point of that? Why don't you just use the solution that already *works*?

Comment: Is it not possible to get the results using plain requests (`without session`) @baduker?

Comment: @robots.txt it's unclear what you mean by saying "without session". When you use `request.get` the library starts the same "session" just temporary for this one request. Additinally session keeps track of cookies and headers your requests have so if request 1 receives some cookies request 2 will send those cookies back to server. You _should_ use sessions.

Comment: Creating new sessions for new requests while using rotation of proxies (mostly dead) are expensive and that is the reason I wanted to learn how to achieve the same using requests. Do you still think I should stick with session @Granitosaurus?

Comment: Yes, you *really* should use sessions.

Comment: @robots actually not using sessions is _expensive_. Session is there to optimize client code and persist cookies and headers for you automatically. That being said the resource usage is completely irrelevant in your case as your code is IO blocked so you're really focusing on the wrong place to optimize here. If you want more speed rake a look into async/await requests like httpx or aiohttp.

Comment: I've made use of scrapy framework and asyncio library to fetch data from that site in my post. They all lead to failure after a certain amount of requests until there is a random delay in place. As for the persistent cookies are concerned, using rotation of proxies within the same session doesn't really make any sense and that is the reason I wanted to go for requests without session @Granitosaurus.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65378602/9189799) is an answer which clarifies a bit more about why I shouldn't go for persistent cookies when I use proxies. I know this discussion is irrelevant but I started it only when I was suggested here to stick with session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a redirect that occurs on `fetch_detail_page_link`. Python Requests follows redirects by default. When *your* script obtains the cookies, it is only grabbing the cookies for the final request in the chain. You must access the `history` field of the response to see the redirects that were followed. Doing this with a `Session` object worked because it was preserving those cookies for you.

I must agree with others who have commented that it really would be a good idea to use a `Session` object for this. However if you insist on not using `Session`, your script would look like this:

```py
import re
import requests
from requests.cookies import RequestsCookieJar
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin

base = 'https://compranet.hacienda.gob.mx'
link = 'https://compranet.hacienda.gob.mx/web/login.html'
vigen_detail_page = 'https://compranet.hacienda.gob.mx/esop/toolkit/opportunity/current/{}/detail.si'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': "Scraping Your Vigentes 1.0",
}


def grab_first_link_from_dropdown(link):
    r = requests.get(link, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
    category_link = urljoin(base, soup.select_one('ul.dropdown-menu > li > a:contains("Vigentes")').get("href"))
    return category_link


def fetch_detail_page_link(cat_link):
    res = requests.get(cat_link, headers=headers)
    cookies = RequestsCookieJar()  # create empty cookie jar
    for r in res.history:
        cookies.update(r.cookies)  # merge in cookies from each redirect response
    cookies.update(res.cookies)  # merge in cookies from the final response

    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
    for items in soup.select("table.list-table > tbody.list-tbody > tr"):
        target_link = items.select_one("a.detailLink").get("onclick")
        detail_num = re.findall(r"goToDetail\(\'(\d+?)\'", target_link)[0]
        inner_link = vigen_detail_page.format(detail_num)
        yield cookies, inner_link


def get_content(cookies, inner_link):
    res = requests.get(inner_link, headers=headers, cookies=cookies)
    if not res.ok:
        print("Got bad response %s :(" % res.status_code)
        return "", ""
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
    try:
        expediente = soup.select_one(".form_question:contains('Código del Expediente') + .form_answer").get_text(strip=True)
    except AttributeError:
        expediente = ""
    try:
        descripcion = soup.select_one(".form_question:contains('Descripción del Expediente') + .form_answer").get_text(strip=True)
    except AttributeError:
        descripcion = ""
    return expediente, descripcion


if __name__ == '__main__':
    category_link = grab_first_link_from_dropdown(link)
    for cookie, detail_page_link in fetch_detail_page_link(category_link):
        print(get_content(cookie, detail_page_link))
```